# VLOOKUP Function is not returning any value above a particular number in my dataset

Tags: excel, vlookup, data-analysis

I'm trying to use vlookup function in my shark tank dataset. when I'm entering any value up to 35 it is working fine but after 35 when I enter 36 it is showing N/A in the cell.
the formula I'm using: `=VLOOKUP(AD34,Table1,3,0)`

[picture of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MipWE.png)

Comment: By referring to Table1 in your formula your lookup will look in the first column of your table. Your screenshot in combination with your example makes me wonder if you may want to look from the second column instead. If you were to look from the first column, note there's duplicate values and vlookup would only show the result of the first found matching row.

Comment: @P.b Thanks I recognized the problem,but can you tell how to look from the second column instead of the first in vlookup function.

Comment: Excel allows you to click i the range while editing the formula. When working with table ranges you'll notice a notation like: `Table1[[pitch_number]:[idea]]`